# DIV width to content of other DIVs, floating and centering all

Tags: html, width, css

I would like to achieve something that initialy looked simple to me but turned out to be not.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
border-top: 1px solid black;
margin: 10px;
}
div#all {
border: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id=all>
<div class=first>First</div>
<div class=rowstarter>Row Starter</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=rowstarter>Row Starter</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=rowstarter>Row Starter</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
<div class=content>Content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to get is all DIVs in "content" class are inline-blocks (or floats) set one after another from left to right.

The "rowstarter" class is the same but has to clear the before floats (start a new row).

The "first" DIV has to have a width equal to the content below (so if the window width allows the browser to display 5 "content" DIVs in a row, each having 100px width then "first" has 5 * 100px + 5 * (2 * 10px [margins]) = 600px if 6 "content" DIVs then "first" has 720px width...).

Is this possible without using Javascript, only with CSS?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, but I am sure I can help you, can you visualize it using an image?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I get it, working on an answer. Visualizing would improve it though, so If you have time, please add it.

Comment: Do you mean each "row" needs to be 100% wide, no matter how many divs are in it?

Comment: Hello!

I'm sorry for my broken english. I hope that the image will help: http://i.imgur.com/lz7ySES.png

As you can see, First DIV is equal to width of belows. But all block is centered and other DIVs are floating to the left. Row starters start new rows.

Comment: Hello Derek!

The width of each row is not so important as the width of "first" DIV.
If you're asking if the DIVs should shrink to 100% row width (no matter how many are there) then not - let's say that all DIVs apart from "first" have set width.

Comment: What do need this for, as I am starting to think that if its for showing Data, you could better use an actual table here.

Comment: It's not for the data. Well it is, as most of websites, but it's not a regular table. It's just a kind of graphic concept.

Comment: Also the table would not work properly as the number of "content" DIVs can vary from one to even 20 (then the row is actualy not one row but many rows, depending on the window width). This is why floating or inline-blocks goes to play.

Comment: @friedman, using the `colspan` attribute would take care of variable numbers of rows if you were to use a table.

Comment: You never know how many DIVs are able to be in one row (depending on window width) so colspan is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7kp/23/) which I believe answers your question.

First, you have to give `#all` and each child div, **except for `.first`**, a left float:

```
#all,
#all div {
    float: left;
}
#all .first {
    float: none;
}
```

Then, clear `.rowstarter` on the left.

```
#all .rowstarter {
    clear:left;
}
```

You actually don't need the "content" class at all (and I would recommend removing it, as it clutters the code and adds to the page weight).

**Edit:** If you add a `.rowstarter` div in front of the `.first` div, `.rowstarter` has to have a fixed width and the left margin of `.first` needs to increase by the sum of the width and margins of `.rowstarter`.

```
#all .rowstarter {
    width: 100px; // arbitrary fixed width
    margin: 10px; // you've given all divs inside #all this margin, just restating for emphasis
}
#all .rowstarter + .first {
    margin-left: 130px; // width of .rowstarter, plus its left and right margins and .first's original 10px left margin
}
```

To achieve the centering of `div#all` you have to add a wrapper around it, then apply the following css trick:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
#all {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Comment: Well... thank you but it doesn't work. First is wider than the longest row below it so this is not it. Also the content closed in "all" is not centered on the page. It sticks to the left.

Comment: Actually, no, "first" is not wider.  You have given a 10px margin to each div.  If you inspect the elements, you will see that "first" is actually the exact same width of the widest row when all margins are calculated.  If you don't believe me, remove the margin.

Comment: OK, maybe I described it wrong. The visible border of "first" should go from the left side of the borders in the rows below to the right side of the last DIV's border in the longest row below.

Also the whole block should be centered in the window. Now it sticks to the left.

Comment: I have added a yellow border in the fiddle and changed the div margins so that you can see that `.first` is actually the exact same width as the divs.

Comment: Actually it was my mistake as the question is simplified layout of the website and I cut too much to ask about all details. Why the "first" dynamic width is important is that in the real website concept there actually is a "rowstarter" before it. So the very first row looks like this:

----------- -----
Row Starter First

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question!  However, my answer still works, just remove `width: 100%` from `div.first`.  I've updated my fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see any updates in the fiddle. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: They should be there.  I've clicked 'update' again just in case.  Anyway, all I did was remove `width:100%;` from `.first` and stick a `div.rowstarter` in front of it so you can see it working.

Comment: Well... I still can see only the first version of your fiddle.

Anyway I edited it manually. This solutions does not work as `.first` div does not achieve the right end of the rows placed below.

Imagine the line from the left side of `.rowstarter` DIV in any row to the right side of the farest DIV in the longest row. `.first` should fill the space between where it starts (after the very first `.rowstarter`) to the right side of the rows below.

Also all `div`s as a block should be centered on the page.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it does precisely that. But I realise why you're seeing the old fiddle:  I didn't realise that the URL changed every time I updated. (sigh)  Here's the URL, and I'll update the link in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7kp/19/.

Comment: Thank you Derek, it's close but there is still the issue. Maybe it's my mistake again (wrong description). If so then let me know. Anyway, there should be a margin between `.first` and its `.rowstarter`, just the same as between any `.rowstarter` and `.content` below. Now it starts just in the same place as the whole row. Also `.first` text should be aligned to the left.

Comment: I have edited my answer and updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7kp/22/.  Just removed the center align, which you initially stated was a requirement but now say is not.  I have taken care of the spacing of the `.first` div when it is preceded by `.rowstarter`, but for this to work `.rowstarter` has to have a fixed width.

Comment: Center align of the **whole block of divs** is the requirement, I never said anything else :) Apart from that the rest looks very good! But I'm affraid that the center alignment (center the "all" `div` on the page) is very tricky though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7kp/23/.  To achieve the centering you'll have to add a wrapper around `div#all`.  I fiddled with widths in my fiddle because of the limited space provided in the iframe.

Comment: Thank you that you are still here! Well... It is really really close but here comes the trickiest part. `.first` is now wider than the rows below in case when the row breaks to two (when next `.content` moves to next line). In fact this is a come back to the start because it was my biggest problem - how to force `.first` (and `#all` at the same time) to shrink to the width of the broken row?

Comment: @friedman, I think we've reached the extent of what we can do with just CSS.  To make sure what you described in your last comment happens, you will have to use JavaScript.  If you found my help at all useful, I hope you'll give me an upvote.  I'm sorry I wasn't able to give you a 100% satisfactory solution, but I hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As the number of content `div`s is going to be dynamic, you will need to use javascript in order to achieve what you want.  There is no css that will allow you to do calculations to work out a percentage width based on number of child elements.

The alternative to javascript would be if you knew how many `div`s are in each row while you are generating your html, you can add inline styles for the widths

Here are some examples

[Pure css (needs html layout change)](http://jsfiddle.net/6NQHA/)
[jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/6NQHA/1/)

Comment: Thank you, Pete. This is kind of solution but not exact. It gives some ideas though.

Please remember that the number of content 'div's is unknown but the most important thing is that we don't know how many 'div's will be able to be in one row (depending on window width). So there might be a possibility that we have 6 'div's but the row is actually divided into two subrows width 3 'div's each.

Comment: As long as you're not trying to make each div's width dynamic proportional to the row width, you can do this with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a jsFiddle that probably answers your question. It now also contains the width but the added code is without any width so you are free to use what you want now

http://jsfiddle.net/agtFw/3

The HTML:

```
<div id="all">
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="content rowstarter">Row Starter</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content rowstarter">Row Starter</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content rowstarter">Row Starter</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

it is no problem to give 2 or more classes to a div and it helps you a lot sometimes!

and the css:

```
div {
border-top: 1px solid black;
margin: 10px;
}

div.content
{
    float:left;
}

div.rowstarter
{
    clear:left;
}

div#all {
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as it ignores the requirement concerning width.

Comment: Hello Nick!

Thank you but it's only a part of the solution. The tricky part comes when you try to center all the DIVs (closed in DIV named "all") and to get the right width of "first" DIV.

Comment: You are both right, working on it. Please tell me if the jsFiddle now suit your need more, with the width on 100%

Comment: Please remember that the row width is dynamic and is depending on a number of DIVs inside it and on browser's window width (if there are more DIVs than the window width then the row continue below in the next line).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should be going home now, I'll come back to this as soon as I can. I know it is possible what you want, eventually you have to use javascript though.